# How do you say "three times a month" in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, recurring-events

We say *semimonthly* when we describe something happening twice a month. for example "a semimonthly publication", "a semimonthly meeting", etc. Is there any word we can use to describe something that happens three times a month; preferably one word?

Comment: Have the meeting four times a month, then you can just use *weekly* ;)

Comment: It looks like you are asking this question, also without answer: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_prefix_that_means_one_third

Comment: Given the potential confusion, wouldn't it easier just to say "every ten days?"

Comment: *Sesquiweekly?*

Answer (score 10):

*Trimonthly* is, in fact, already in [several dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=trimonthly&ls=a). Problem is, unlike its counterparts *bimonthly* and *biweekly*, trimonthly is only defined as *occurring every three months*, sans a secondary *three-times-a-month* meaning.

I would recommend *thrice-monthly*, if you needed to form a single word.

> *The committee meetings will occur thrice-monthly until this matter is
>   resolved.*

```
EDITS:
```

As was pointed out in the comment below, the hyphen could be omitted as well.

Also, I'll restate my opening remarks, but add some links:

Although *bimonthly* can be used either way (see [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bimonthly)), that doesn't appear to be the case for *trimonthly* (see [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trimonthly), [here](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/trimonthly), [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/trimonthly), and [here](http://www.yourdictionary.com/trimonthly)).  In light of such evidence, I'd be hesitant to use *trimonthly* when meaning "three times each month."

Comment: +1 for the dictionary support. However, thrice-monthly (with the hyphen) looks awkward; in my own use, I would simply use it as two words. I'm not sure there is a *single* word.

Comment: @zpletan: Astute feedback – thanks!  I almost added a comment that the hyphen could be omitted; perhaps I should've listened to my instincts there.

Comment: also __trimester__ for a three month period.

Comment: Why bother to use an obsolete form "thrice"-- why not just say e.g. "a three-times-monthly meeting"?

Comment: @NeilCoffey: compactness – though I have no problem with your suggestion, either.  One is wordier, one is more archaic: pick your poison.

Comment: It's a matter of preference, but I´d say that if you're going to repeat the phrase so many times that a single extra word/syllable is an issue, then you may as well just invent some term/abbreviation, e.g. define and then write "a 3/m meeting". It also depends on your definition of "compactness": even if you hijacked "trimestrial" and redefined to mean what you want here, it still has the same number of syllables as "three times monthly". It's *visually* more compact, but does that even matter?

Comment: P.S. If you want a pointlessly overengineered word, I quite like the invention "tertimestrial" :)

Comment: @NeilCoffey: I didn't say an extra syllable was an issue; I merely tried to answer the original question.  Because the O.P. asked for "one word," I valued compactness in my suggestion.

Comment: @NeilCoffey _Trimestrial_ has of one heavy syllable (unaccented) and three light ones (one accented, two unaccented); _three-times-monthly_ has three heavy syllables (all accented) and one light one (unaccented). In other words, _trimestrial_ has one stress peak in five morae; _three-times-monthly_ has three stress peaks in eight morae. That’s a fairly big difference.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen that in an official dictionary but I have read in several scientific papers in the past the word "decadaily" used for "every ten days".
It made sense to me since "deca" means ten in Greek and it is used in English as a prefix indicating the number 10.

Answer (score 2):

I like thrice-monthly. It is essentially one word, it means three times a month and, unlike trimonthly, is not easily confused to mean 'every three months' instead of 'three times a month'.

Comment: +1 I also like the fact it has a pleasing Ye Olde-fashioned English ring to it too.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the rare ***trimensual***.

> *These forms also exist for the month, although rarely used in English. Nevertheless, I think they sound right, so to speak.*
>
> *bimensual (adj.), bimensually (adv.) = twice a month*
>
> *bimestral (adj.), bimestrally (adv.) = every other month*
>
> *trimensual (adj.), trimensually (adv.) = three times a month*
>
> *trimestral (adj.), trimestrally (adv.) = every third month*
>
> *(Note the connection to the word trimester.) Latin had no week, and it seems especially silly to slice up a day in this way (as opposed to speaking of hours), so I guess that's pretty much as far as it goes.*
>
> [The Straight Dope](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?p=18749580)

Comment: Trimensual is the first word that came to my mind too, but my spellchecker doesn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such a word.

I presume *trimonthly* would be understood since the days of Harry Potter and the Triwizard Tournament!

Comment: I would understand trimonthly as something occurring once in three months rather than three times in a month

Comment: @Armin OALD definition of bimonthly is: "produced or happening every two months or twice each month" I would presume that trimonthly would have a similar meaning if it existed!

Comment: Indeed, but the definition of trimonthly is "produces or happening every three months" only (see J.R.'s answer). But in any case I think that it's not the definitions that matter. Honestly, when someone said to you "a trimonthly meeting", what would you assume - once in three months or three times a month?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: I would probably assume 3x in one month, too.  But, if I was the meeting's organizer, and I knew what the dictionary said, I would avoid _trimonthly_.  Many folks are already adept enough at finding ways to skip meetings; I wouldn't want to give my more educated invitees a legitimate excuse to miss a follow-up meeting – a meeting they can claim they thought was two months down the road.

Comment: I stand corrected, dictionary evidence (JR) is overwhelming.. but just out of curiosity, why not just say three times a month??

Answer (score -2):

Decadaily implies that the meetings happen every ten days and therefore could not happen on the same day of the week.