# Is "tri-quarterly" a real English word meaning 3 times a year?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, is-it-a-word

Is "tri-quarterly" a real English word meaning 3 times a year? Are there any other words that mean 3 times a year?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18540/biweekly-bimonthly-biannual-and-bicentennial

Comment: Also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64086/how-do-you-say-three-times-a-month-in-one-word

Comment: A superficial use of google leads one to think that this is 'not a word'. It is used as a title of a literary magazine, but that's about it. I don't think there's anything useful one can say about this word that is anything but speculative.

Comment: something published every four months might be most acceptably and clearly described as being published "thrice yearly" or "three times a year"

Comment: Tri-quarterly, absolutely, means either (a) every three quarters or (b) three times a quarter.  It's that simple. The OPs specific question: "does it mean three times per year": answer is **absolutely, definitely NOT**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If "tri-quarterly" means anything, surely it would be every third quarter (every nine months). Or possibly three times a quarter, which is monthly. You can't redefine a quarter as a third, though.

Three times a year is ***triannual*** — not *triennial* which is every three years. You could also say ***every four months***; "every four months" is preferable because it removes the possibility of confusion between *triennial* and *triannual*.

Comment: The OED records the adjective _triannual_ as obsolete, but gives it both as ‘occurring every three years’ and ‘occurring thrice a year’. It gives the adjective ‘triennial’ as ‘existing or lasting for three years’ and ‘recurring every three years’.

Comment: Triannually was what I found as well, but not in the dictionary, but I couldn't find any validation for tri-quarterly although a few magazines use it that are published 3 times a year. I will accept this answer if I don't get any other suggestions.

Comment: It is possible that whoever used the term wanted to convey the idea that the three issues are published in three-month intervals, i.e. quarterly (say, in March, June,and September), and that one quarter is then skipped (in this example, there is no issue in December). *Tri-quarterly* would, however, still be a very bad term to use for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A word that I find used a lot is: [tertial](https://second.wiki/wiki/tertial)

> Tertial is a foreign word from Latin meaning a third . In the temporal sense, a third is understood to mean a third of a year , i.e. a period of four months .

Answer (score 0):

Trimester Trimester · Academic term, a trimester system divides the academic year into three terms

Comment: Confusingly, each term is usually about 13 weeks (the same length as a quarter of the year) to allow for holidays.

Comment: @Peter Also confusingly _trimester_ is used when referring to human pregnancy. In this context there are three trimesters in a full-term pregnancy each trimester being roughly three months or thirteen weeks long. Trimester neatly divides a thirty-six week pregnancy into three parts and I understand that, if the terms are of equal length, how trimester gives the length of the terms but I don't quite get how _trimester_ can be said to divide a fifty-two week year into three parts.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Could you [edit] your answer to explain clearly how this answers the question about *tri-quarterly* please?

Comment: @BoldBen Actually *trimester* means a 3-month period, so in an academic year you would have a trimester (term), break, trimester, break, trimester, long break. This is consistent with the meaning for pregnancy. I am afraid I confused myself!