# Monthly , bi-monthly , quarterly and

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to define a period of four months?

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/triannual although that definition does allow for irregular frequencies

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83424/is-tri-quarterly-a-real-english-word-meaning-3-times-a-year

Comment: Triannual is a frequency measure and has no connection whatsoever to a measure of time.

Comment: [This question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83424/is-tri-quarterly-a-real-english-word-meaning-3-times-a-year) covers the title of your question (adverbs), and [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23262/is-there-a-proper-term-to-describe-1-3-of-a-year-4-months) its body (nouns).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is: ***quadrimester***.  It means a period of four months, and is analogous to *trimester* for a period of three months.  It is used almost exclusively in academic contexts.

Dutch and German have the same word, while French, Italian, Spanish, and Portuguese all spell it *quadrimestre*.

Comment: A question, an answer .. a miracle on the internet  :)

Comment: I would say the word is tertial and that is a word used in many languages. https://second.wiki/wiki/tertial